# How to track user location when app is in killed state in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, location, user-location

I want to track the user location in my ios app using objective-c even if app is in killed state/ suspended state.
please help.

Comment: Show us the code that you're going to run when the app isn't running.  Asking for help to create a paradox is not a useful expenditure of time.

Comment: @Avi, You can implement the code in the `applicationIsWaitingForGodot` AppDelegate method

Comment: @avy i havent done any code when the app isnt running,
i wanted to know how to implement signification location change or is there anything to do to check for the device location within a period of time even when the app is terminated

Comment: i want to know in which state of United states, the device/user is currently located at even if the app is not running

Answer (score 0):

Use Pushkit, when your server will send a remote notification then application automatically goes in background state.

Comment: You can only only use Pushkit if you have a VoIP app